# Square Peg Problem and curve density

Tags: gn.general-topology

Square Peg Problem (or conjecture) is so famous. [See this article](https://www.ams.org/notices/201404/rnoti-p346.pdf)

Let $CS:=\{\gamma:S^1\longmapsto\mathbb{R}^2 | \;\;\text {Square Peg Problem is true}\}$ and $C=\{\Upsilon:S^1\longmapsto\mathbb{R}^2 \}$.

Is this true that $CS$ is dense in the set $C$? Is there any results in this direction?

Comment: Well, wikipedia says that polygons are in $CS$ and if they are not dense in $C$ in topology you are thinking about then you should definitely tell us which topology you are imposing on $C$. Actually, for dense subset of polygons it is obvious that they are in $CS$ -- start with arbitrary polygon and add  small square bump on one of it sides.